# How can I attach to a Docker container in Python and then execute MySQL commands?

Tags: python, bash, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to automate my Docker containers after they have been instanced by configuring a few things via a Python script.

```
#/bin/bash

# Permissions - These need sorting
chmod -R 777 example.co.uk

# Instance the container and build the OS
docker-compose up --build -d

# Initiate the Laravel App
docker exec app php artisan key:generate
docker exec app php artisan config:clear

# Add the Mysql user
docker exec mysql bash
```

The issue I have now is that `bash` returns a new terminal instance of the containers CLI. I need to somehow attach to that and run `mysql -u root -p` and then attach to that to enter the password and execute some SQL commands.

Running `mysql -u root -p` returns `mysql command not found` as I'm not in the returned bash CLI. The SQL commands I then need to run are:

```
GRANT ALL ON laravel.* TO 'laraveluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somesecurepassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I have substantially researched but the issue I have is I don't know what I'm searching for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use an ordinary MySQL client library here.  You don't need debugging tools like `docker exec` or to try to interact with a shell.  Also consider using either the environment variable settings in the [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) or the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory to set up an initial username and password.

Comment: I'm totally new to docker, this is all a learning project. I've looked into `entrypoint: ....` but cannot find any resources online to point me into the direction of initialising the database user within an entrypoint command in my docker-compose.yml. Could you perhaps point me to that? I really appreciate you sharing your knowledge @DavidMaze

Comment: On top of this, I can see now there are the username and password environmental variables I can use to do this. & if you want to create that as an answer, that'd be awesome. But, for future reference, I'd love to understand your second option incase an environmental variable is not available @DavidMaze